# Bottom navigation with scrollable toolbar in coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, scrollable, bottomnavigationview

Hei Guys,

I'm trying to get the scroll_behaviour done right for my layout.
My problem is that if I wrap the bottom navigation into a relative layout and put my main content above it, then the bottom navigation scrolls out of screen when the toolbar hides. If I put the bottom navigation as another direct child of my coordinator layout, then the main content is behind my BottomNavigation. I do not wanna solve it by adding padding/margin to the bottom of my main navigation. Do you have any hints or ideas ?

Another thing is that the ripple effect of my bottom navigation is only visible on top of the bottom navigation and not above my main content.

Adding a scroll_behaviour to the bottom navigation didn't work either. I wanna try a fixed bottom navigation, or add a scroll out animation while scrolling down like shown in the google material design guidelines.

Here a screenshot:

[image: App Screenshot]

This is the layout code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    <com.getproperly.properlyv2.classes.misc.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/rl"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"
    />

<com.getproperly.properlyv2.classes.misc.SelfAwareFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/rl"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:layout_behavior="com.getproperly.properlyv2.classes.misc.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"/>
```

Appreciate any help!
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

you can wrap the coordinator layout inside relative layout and take bottom navigation out in that relative layout parallel to the coordinator layout.

```
<RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
...
...
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Umar. is it a good practice to put a Coordinator inside of another view ? I though I've read somewhere that the coordinator layout should be the parent layout.

Comment: Any layout container can be parent and in in your particular case, bottom navigation is not designed with coordinator layout, so you cannot place bottom navigation directly inside the coordinator layout to work properly.

Comment: another thing you can do is place the bottom navigation inside the relative layout within your coordinatorLayout, but I don't know whether it will disable the scroll or not for bottom nav.

Comment: btw do you need the bottom navigation background transparent ?